# 4-ary heaps in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

Binary heaps are commonly used in e.g. priority queues. The basic idea is that of an incomplete heap sort: you keep the data sorted "just enough" to get out the top element quickly.

While 4-ary heaps are theoretically worse than binary heaps, they do also have some benefits. For example, they will require less heap restructuring operations (as the heap is much shallower), while obvisouly needing more comparisons at each level. But (and that probably is their main benefit?) they may have better CPU cache locality. So some sources say that 3-ary and 4-ary heaps outperform both Fibonacci and binary heaps *in practise*.
They should not be much harder to implement, the additional cases are just some extra `if` cases.

Has anyone experimented with 4-ary heaps (and 3-ary) for priority queues and done some benchmarking?
In Java you never know if they are faster or slower before you benchmarked them extensively.
And from all I've found via Google, it may be quite language and use case dependant. Some sources say that they found 3-ary to perform best for them.

Some more points:

- `PriorityQueue` obviously is a binary heap. But the class for example also lacks bulk loading and bulk repair support, or `replaceTopElement` which can make a huge difference. Bulk loading for example is `O(n)` instead of `O(n log n)`; bulk repair is essentially the same after adding a larger set of candidates. Tracking which parts of the heap are invalid can be done with a single integer. `replaceTopElement` is much cheaper than `poll` + `add` (just consider how a poll is implemented: replace the top element with the very last)
- While heaps of course are popular for complex objects, the priority often is an integer of double value. It's not as if we are comparing strings here. Usually it is a (primitive) *priority*
- PQs are often used just to get the top k elements. For example A*-search can terminate when the goal is reached. All the less good paths are then discarded. So the queue is never completely emptied. In a 4-way heap, there is *less* order: approximately half as much (half as many parent nodes). So it will impose less order on these elements that are not needed. (This of course differs if you intend to empty your heap completely, e.g. because you are doing heap sort.)

Comment: What specific information are you interested in?  How does this apply to Java?

Comment: You can't do register-level CPU optimizations in Java. So the reasoning "I can fit a 2-way heap in CPU register operations" does probably not apply to Java. The question is at the end: has anyone benchmarked 4-way heaps in Java?

Comment: Your question makes little sense to me. Registers have nothing to do with the CPU cache AFAIK. You do need more memory accesses per level, but that ought to be mitigated by visiting fewer levels.

Comment: I haven't benchmarked or anything, but -- it seems like a quaternary heap would be, at best, half the height of a binary heap. So you would cut the number of restructurings in half; but each restructuring would require three comparisons instead of just one. So in theory, it should actually be 50% *slower*. (That's the theory. In practice, locality of reference would probably benefit the quaternary heap slightly; but I still don't *think* it would be enough to make it a win, especially if the comparison operations are at *all* expensive.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap says "d-ary heaps have better memory cache behavior than a binary heap, allowing them to run more quickly in practice despite having a theoretically larger worst-case running time." and "in practice d-ary heaps are generally at least as fast, and often faster, than Fibonacci heaps for this application". There is a *gap between theoretically optimal and in practice optimal*, in particular with Java. That's why I asked if anyone has **benchmarked**.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: But that's exactly the opposite of what you wrote in your question. In your question, you wrote that a quaternary heap would theoretically be faster, but might be slower in practice because of cache behavior. Wikipedia is saying the reverse: that a quaternary heap would theoretically be slower, but might be faster in practice because of cache behavior. (Which, you'll note, is also more or less what I wrote.)

Comment: **Whichever holds in theory: what do Java benchmarks say?** That is what I'm asking about. I care little if it's now better in Big-O notation and worse in CPU cache theory, or the other way around.

Comment: @ruakh It's actually 4 comparisons per level (instead of 2), but there are half as many levels. So same number of comparisons, but half as many swaps, plus better L1 cache locality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @ErichSchubert's suggestion, I have taken the implementations from [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) and modified them into a 4-ary heap. It was a bit trick to get the indexing right, as a lot of the publications around 4-ary heaps use formulas for 1-indexed arrays?!?

Here are some early benchmark results, based on the ELKI unit test. 200000 `Double` objects are preallocated (to avoid measuring memory management too much) and shuffled.

As a warmup, 10 iterations are performed for each heap, for benchmarking 100 iterations, but I'll probably try to scale this up further. 10-30 seconds isn't that realiably for benchmarking yet, and OTOH I should try to measure standard deviations, too.
In each iteration, the 200000 elements are added to the heap, then half of them are polled again. Yes, the workload could also be made more complex.

Here are the results:

- My 4-ary `DoubleMinHeap`: 10.371
- ELKI `DoubleMinHeap`:  12.356
- ELKI `Heap<Double>`: 37.458
- Java `PriorityQueue<Double>`: 45.875

So the difference between the 4-ary heap (probably not yet L1 cache-aligned!) and the ELKI heap for *primitive* doubles is not too big. Well, 10%-20% or so; it could be worse.

The difference between a heap for primitive `double`s and a heap for `Double` objects is much larger. And the ELKI `Heap` is indeed quite clearly faster than the Java `PriorityQueue` (but that one seems to have a high variance).
There was a slight "bug" in ELKI, though - at least the primitive heaps did not use the bulk loading code yet. It's there, it's just not being used, as every elements repairs the heap immediately instead of delaying this until the next `poll()`. I fixed this for my experiments, essentially by removing a few lines and adding one `ensureValid();` call. Furthermore, I also don't have a 4-ary object heap yet, and I havn't include ELKI's `DoubleObjectMinHeap` yet... quite a lot to benchmark, and I'll probably give caliper a try for that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Yes, the heaps are still a work in progress. The bulk loading so far does not seem to improve performance, so we left it disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Not benchmarked it myself, but have a few points to make that are relevant.

Firstly, note that the standard Java implementation of PriorityQueue uses a binary heap:

- http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/PriorityQueue.java

It is plausibly the case that, despite the cache locality benefit of n-ary heaps, binary heaps are still the best solution on average. Below are some slightly hand-wavy reasons why this might be the case:

- For most interesting objects, **comparison costs** are probably much more significant than cache locality effects in the heap data structure itself. n-ary heaps require more comparisons. This probably is enough on its own to outweigh any cache locality effect in the heap itself.
- If you were simply making a heap of numbers in place (i.e. backed by
  an array of ints or doubles) then I can see that the chache locality
  would be a worthwhile benefit. But this isn't the case: usually you will have a **heap of object references**. Cache locality on the object references themselves is then less useful, since each
  comparison will require following at least one extra reference to
  examine the referenced object and its fields.
- The **common case** for priority heaps is probably quite a small heap. If you are hitting it sufficiently that you care about it from a performance perspective, it's probably all in the L1 cache anyway. So no cache locality benefit for the n-ary heap anyway.
- It's easier to handle a binary heap with **bitwise ops**. Sure it's not a big advantage, but every little helps....
- **Simpler algorithms** are generally faster than more complex ones, all else being equal, simply because of a lower constant overhead. You get benefits like lower instruction cache usage, higher likelihood of the compiler being able to find smart optimisations etc. Again this works in favour of the binary heap.

Obviously of course you'd need to do your own benchmarks on your own data before you come to a real conclusion about whether which performs the best (and if the difference is enough to care about, which I personally doubt....)

**EDIT**

Also, I did write a priority heap implementation using an array of primitive keys that may be of interest given the original poster mentioned primitive keys in the comment below:

- https://github.com/mikera/mikera/blob/master/src/main/java/mikera/util/RankedQueue.java

This could probably be hacked into an n-ary version for benchmarking purposes relatively easily if anyone was interested in running a test.

Comment: I have to make a few comments: `PriorityQueue` is a bit lacking, for example it should be using bulk loading and bulk additions, so I wouldn't take it as a reference. Then even when storing complex objects, the sorting *key* often is primitive, e.g. an integer or double priority, think of A* search. A 4-ary heap should also work with bitwise operations, just by shifting 2 instead of 1 and have the same overhead. The 4-ary heap is *less sorted* actually. If you do not empty the heap (e.g. A* search), this actually should save you comparisons. But it clearly depends on the use case.

Comment: Sounds like you have a specific use case in mind if you can use primitive keys? If so then sure, a specialized n-ary heap with a separate array of primitive keys may be better. A general purpose priority heap in Java would however typically need to work with Comparators or Comparable instances rather than primitive keys.

Comment: Added a link to an old priority queue implementation I made a while back that uses primitive doouble keys - may be of interest....

Comment: Consider A* search for example. How would your `compareTo` look like? For me it's usually a `Double.compare(this.priority, other.priority)`. I'm not recomputing paths while repairing the heap.

Comment: Sure that's the compareTo implementation I'd expect in that case. But that is still two references followed. Make those String keys and it is probably four. etc. The point is that following these extra references is extra memory access cost in an n-ary heap (which does more comparisons than a binary heap). Unless you actually copy these keys into an array within the heap itself (see my RankedQueue implementation for an example of this), this probably kills any benefit from cache locality in n-ary heaps.

Comment: A good read on this topic: https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1814327
(Although this one is on two different memory layouts for binary heaps with secondary memory) Note that memory locality also may refer to pointers I guess. So a 4-ary heap may also have 4 related pointers already in the L1 cache, where a binary heap only has 2. So even for `compareTo` methods, locality should make a difference!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I have not benchmarked 4-ary heaps yet.</strike> I'm currently trying to optimize our own heap implementations, and I'm trying 4-ary heaps there, too. And you are right: we will need to benchmark this carefully, as it is easy to get mislead by implementation differences and Hotspot optimization will heavily affect the results. Plus, small heaps will probably show different performance characteristics than large heaps.

The Java `PriorityQueue` is a very *simple* heap implementation, but that means Hotspot will optimize it well. It's not bad at all: most people would implement a worse heap. But, for example, it indeed does not do efficient bulk loads or bulk adds (bulk repairs). However, in my experiments it was hard to consistently beat this implementation even in simulations with repeated inserts, unless you go for really large heaps. Furthermore, in many situations it pays off to replace the top element in the heap instead of `poll()` + `add()`; this is not supported by java's `PriorityQueue`.

Some of the performance gains in ELKI (and I've seen you are an ELKI user) across versions are actually due to improved heap implementations. But it's an up and down, it's hard to predict which heap variation performs best across real workloads. The key benefit of our implementation is probably to have a "replaceTopElement" function. You can inspect the code here:

[SVN de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.heap package](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/browser/elki/trunk/src/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/utilities/datastructures/heap)

You will notice we have a whole *set* of heaps there. They are optimized for different stuff, and will need some more refactoring. A number of these classes are actually generated from templates, similar to what [GNU Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) does. The reason is that Java can be quite costly when managing boxed primitives, so it does pay off to have primitive versions. (yes, there are plans to split this out into a separate library. It's just not of high priority.)

Note that ELKI deliberately does not endorse the `java.util.Collections` API. We have found in particular the `java.util.Iterator` class to be quite costly, and thus try to encourage people to use [C++-style iterators](http://www.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/research/KDD/ELKI/release0.5.5/doc/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/utilities/iterator/Iter.html) throughout ELKI:

```
for (Iter iter = ids.iter(); iter.valid(); iter.advance()) {
```

often saves a lot of unnecessary object creations over the `java.util.Iterator` API. Plus, these iterators can have *multiple* (and *primitive*) value getters; where `Iterator.next()` is a mixture of a getter and the advance operator.

Ok, I have drifted off too much now, back to the topic of 4-ary heaps:

If you intend to try out 4-ary heaps, I suggest you start with the `ObjectHeap` class there.

**Update**: I've been microbenchmarking, but the results so far are inconclusive. It's hard to beat `PriorityQueue` consistently. In particular bulk loading and bulk repairs do not seem to cut anything in my benchmark - probably they cause HotSpot to optimize less, or de-optimize at some point. As often, a simpler Java code is faster than a complex logic. So far, 4-ary heaps without bulk-loading seem to work best. I haven't tried 5-ary yet. 3-ary are about equal with 4-ary heaps; and the memory layout of 4-ary is a bit nicer. I'm also considering to try a heap-of-heaps approach to safe array resizing. But I expect that the increased code complexity means it will run slower in practise.